# Unable to resolve service for type 'IPipelineConfiguration' while attempting to activate 'CustomPipeline'

Tags: sitecore-commerce, commerce-engine

I've defined a custom pipeline in my `ConfigureSitecore`, but when I run the engine I get the following error:

> InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Sitecore.Framework.Pipelines.IPipelineConfiguration' while attempting to activate 'CustomPipeline'.

`IPipelineConfiguration` is the first argument of the pipeline implementation, and is simply passed to the base constructor, so I'm not sure why it wouldn't be configured in the DI container.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer is that the custom pipeline needs to accept the argument as `IPipelineConfiguration<ICustomPipelineInterface>`

When you configure a pipeline via `pipelines.AddPipeline<T,K>` or `pipelines.ConfigurePipeline<T>`, you're actually configuring a DI-injected service for `IPipelineConfiguration<T>`. When the pipeline is created at runtime, it needs the typed service in order to get access to the configured blocks.

As to why the base `Pipeline` class doesn't accept the generic form of `IPipelineConfiguration`: the pipeline interface is not one of the generic type parameters for `Pipeline` so it has no reference to it. It could have been added, but my only guess as to why it wasn't is that it would have made declarations of pipeline classes very "wordy".